# Update Mojarra in Jboss AS 6

Tags: java, application-server, jboss6.x

I've been using glassfish and it has an update utility guide that keeps the server up to date. Is there anything like this in Jboss AS? Or how can I update any lib? To be more specific, I want to update mojarra to its latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps to upgrade Mojarra are described in the **Jboss 6 upgrading JSF** section of the web page http://entjavastuff.blogspot.com/2010/07/migrating-to-jboss-51-from-jboss-42x.html